# what does "##" symbol mean in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Macro expansion in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672618/macro-expansion-in-c)
>   [What is the purpose of the ## operator in C++, and what is it called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121971/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-operator-in-c-and-what-is-it-called)

What does "##" symbol mean in C++? I came across with it while I was reading someone's source code. More specifically, what does this statement mean:

```
if ( v > ## = 0.1 * threshold )
```

Comment: I have seen this before.. it has to be a duplicate

Comment: @0A0D: I might put that on my wall.

Comment: @Tomalak: :) Google is not friendly to ##.. hard to search for this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a `#define` macro, `##` is a preprocessor token, which says to paste the surrounding two things together.  So assuming you saw this within a `#define`, it is a very strange way of writing

```
if ( v >= 0.1 * threshold )
```

If you already subsituted either the `>` or `=`, it's not quite so strange.  Just a somewhat strange trick.

Comment: Only if the code was part of a macro definition. There was no evidence of that in the question.

Comment: (And [it _does_ have to be part of a macro definition](http://www.ideone.com/BeAbn).)

Comment: @Tomalak: If the code compiles, it must be part of a macro definition.  I think it's reasonable to guess that the code compiles.

Comment: It actually is a macro definition, thanks guys.

Comment: @small_potato: You _must_ include that sort of thing in your post. It's utterly crucial. What you called a "statement" is in fact nothing of the sort in your code.

Comment: @Tomalak: it's most useful a part of a macro, but I don't believe it's restricted to use in the body of a macro. Do you have a standards reference? (If only because I'm not finding any free ones on a quick earch.)

Comment: @geekosaur: I don't need one. I demonstrated that it's invalid outside of a macro definition. And, if you're still not convinced, `##` is defined in `cpp.concat` and not given semantics elsewhere.

Comment: @geekosaur: Feel free to decode the C++ grammar if you _still_ need proof. You'll find the most convincing argument there.

Answer (score 2):

It's a preprocessor token:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing. This is an error.

Are you sure that the code after `##` isn't a comment, and that the conditional is not continued properly on the next ensuing line?

Alternatively, the code you pasted may be part of a line that constitutes a macro definition (but you showed no evidence of that, so I won't answer that *different* question here).

<sub>(You see how *context* matters in questions like this?)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`##` tells `cpp` to paste the tokens before and after it together.  In this case, I would have to guess that for some reason the programmer needed to avoid having an actual `>=` token, possibly to avoid confusing some other preprocessor (documentation generator or whatever), so has `cpp` assemble the `>=` from its components.